# Magento - Redirect Customer from Observer Method

Tags: php, magento, redirect

In this event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`, I want the customer to be redirected to an external web page `http://www.example.com/`. For this I am using this code, which is not working at all:-

```
public function moduleMethod() {
    /* @var $response1 Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http */
    $response1 = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();

    /* @var $response2 Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http */
    $response2 = Mage::app()->getResponse();

    $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
    $response1->setRedirect($url);

    return;
}
```

I have used the "`setRedirect()`" method on both these variables "`$response1`" and "`$response2`", but both of them show me the Shopping Cart page, whereas I want to see this page `http://www.example.com/` instead.

What I want:

- I don't want to override the Controller Class, just to redirect the Customer, when I can effectively use the Event Observer process.
- I don't want to use the PHP in-built function "`header()`", when Magento framework provides this functionality in an efficient way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Correct observer code at the bottom.

*A note before I answer: Make sure that the observer is being triggered; step through your code or use `die('here');`. As written, your example method does not have the correct prototype to receive event observer data (missing an argument).*

Using an event observer for redirect logic is totally appropriate in this context, as evinced by the core team explicitly passing the request and response objects in to the observer. Your attempt is good, but I think that you have conditions and configuration which cause execution to flow to `Mage_Checkout_CartController::_goBack()`, specifically to the line

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

So we need to revise our approach. Now, you could prevent any request/response logic from processing after your event observer by manipulating the response and calling the Front Controller's `sendResponse()` method as demonstrated below (**nb: don't do this!**):

```
public function moduleMethod($observer) //note I added a param
{
    /* @var $response1 Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http */
    $response1 = $observer->getResponse(); // observers have event args

    $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
    $response1->setRedirect($url);

    /* SHOULDN'T DO THIS */
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();
}
```

This should work, but I think it mixes up areas of concern by triggering output from an ethereal system component (EDA). Let's see if there's something in the command-control structure which we can use...

Just after the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event execution comes to the cart controller's _goBack() method. The problem with this method name is that it does more than its name implies:

```
/**
 * Set back redirect url to response
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_CartController
 */
protected function _goBack()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
    if ($returnUrl) {
        // clear layout messages in case of external url redirect
        if ($this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
            $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    }
    //...
}
```

It looks like we can just set a `return_url` param on the request object and accomplish what we need.

```
public function moduleMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
}
```

I've tested this, and it should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your awful details in this answer, which are perfectly working! Yes, I've missed mentioning the argument in the method definition, so thanks for correcting me out. It will be great if you can say more on the EDA and its pros & cons on Magento, please!

Comment: Magento has a deep call stack traversing many layers. Without its event architecture, many customizations would be prohibitively invasive and would lead to lots of bugginess.

Comment: When I do this, I get error: External urls redirect to "http://www.google.com/" denied! Does somebody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @J.S you should ask this as a new question.

Comment: @benmarks what about `
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;` to redirect from observer  instead of $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');?
Please shed some light.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy The approach you mention works. However, it involves flushing output inside the event observer, and not from its usual point in the call stack (the Front Controller's `dispatch()` method). This violates the separation of concerns which helps to make Magento (and other MVC frameworks) a little less messy. But, if it works for you and you have a compelling case to take this approach, go for it! (I do cover your proposed solution in my answer, BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

I had to go through `getFront`:

```
public function moduleMethod($observer) {
  $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://www.google.com');
}
```

Comment: If you see the answer given by "Ben", you will see that he used the context object (`$this`) to get the Response `$this->getResponse()` and not the `$observer` object.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but his ultimate solution (i.e., setting the `return_url` param on the request) did not work for something I was doing, and I believe is unintuitive.  This bit of code does what I believe your code was originally trying to do.

Comment: Yes, my requirement was a very specific one, so I believe that the solution provided by "Ben" may not work for you. I'm sorry for the earlier confusion. Also for getting the Response, can you please try `$observer->getResponse()`? I tried it in my Magento local, and it's working for me, instead of using `$observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getResponse()`. Hope it helps.

Comment: The objects available from the argument will be different depending on the event being observed. The response object is effectively a singleton in the application, so the manner by which it is accessed is academic; `Mage::app()->getResponse()` will work "anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [_redirectUrl()](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-controllers-redirecting-to-external-urls/) method , it is used for redirecting to external websites from magento.