# Redirect from observer in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Can I redirect from observer in Magento?

**admin_session_user_login_success**

Here I am checking session and if the session is already created then redirect to same page otherwise redirect to home page.

If yes then how?

Comment: Have you checked these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824551/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236912/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535481/

Comment: Why do you have to do that anyway? seems like a train wreck waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
   $controller = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerAction();
   $controller->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
   $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::app()->getRequest()>getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));
   $controller->getResponse()->sendResponse();
```

Good luck! May the force be with you.