# How can i redirect from Observer with Magento

Tags: magento, redirect, magento-1.7, observers

I am using an Observer to catch that event: `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`

I want that event in order to check the billing address of the customer.

My question is: How can i send a message to the user at this point.When continue button is pressed.

I used the : `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('My message');`

but the message is not shown until you refresh the page.And here is the second question.
How can i redirect the page from that point?
I have use with no luck: `$this->_redirect('*/*/');` and hardcoded urls with no luck.
Ideally i want when the customer presses the continue button, after some checks that i make, the process to be stopped with a message.The observer is checked and it works as it supposed to work.

Hope it make sense..

**EDIT**
That's my code.Just to make sure i'm doing it right:
Model/Observer

```
class Company_Restrictions_Model_Observer {

    public function notifyUser($observer) {
//Lot's off lines are tested here.Nothing seems to work..
$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');

}
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
  <modules>
      <Company_Restrictions>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Company_Restrictions>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <company_restrictions>
             <class>Company_Restrictions_Model</class>
        </company_restrictions>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <company_restrictions>
             <class>Company_Restrictions_Helper</class>
        </company_restrictions>
    </helpers>
    <events>
      <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
        <observers>
          <notify_user>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Company_Restrictions_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>notifyUser</method>
          </notify_user>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>     
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

After debuuging i found out that a lot of functions are giving me error.Undefined method ... for ex: _redirect() or Response() or Body().. Does anyone knows why??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento - Redirect Customer from Observer Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749005/magento-redirect-customer-from-observer-method)

```
public function moduleMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't working..Is there a problem with the event i try to catch?

Answer (score 0):

I have an Observer that successfully redirects and I am just using the setRedirect method:

```
public function moduleMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // get the current front controller
    $frontController = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();

    if(.....)
    {           
         $newUrl = ...;

         $frontController->getResponse()->setRedirect($newUrl);
         Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
         exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference i will give you the answer i got from stackoverflow magento that works:
That's how i managed to make it work..

```
$controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
$result = array();
$result['error'] = '-1';
$result['message'] = 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE';
$controllerAction->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

[Magento Stackoverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/how-to-redirect-from-an-observer-and-send-a-message-to-the-customer)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
$url = YOUR_URL; // e.g. Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login')
Mage::app()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($url)
            ->sendResponse();
```