# send Response function Magento

Tags: magento

Can somebody tell me which is the role of sendResponse() function?

> Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'))->sendResponse();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749005/magento-redirect-customer-from-observer-method

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exacly what I was looking for. It is not given explanation of sendResponse() function, just some advice of using setParam() function instead.

Answer (score 3):

You may find the detailed explanation of the Magento routing system in Alan Storm's blog.

Check the link below:

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch