# Redirect with setParam() function doesn't work

Tags: magento

I want to redirect user to external link. When this statement is executed:

```
$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
```

I always get the following error:

```
External urls redirect to "google.com/"; denied!
```

Did somebody have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following in your Observer

```
<?php 
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse(); 
    // or 
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse(); 
?>
```

More information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749005/magento-redirect-customer-from-observer-method) and [here](http://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/)

Comment: You have to put exit;

Comment: Thanks :) do you know why setParam() function didt'n work? Is this the only way to redirect user?

Comment: Refer to http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_standard_router for more information

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect from `php` in an `ajax` call.

You need to send the right information back from your `php` script to your java script and do the redirect from there, using the parameters you got back from `php`.

*In your ajax response you can check status of request and then you have to check if it's success then you can redirect using javacript*

```
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I don't use ajax. Here is the explanation I followed, but not worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9750868/2618607